# Concatenate a series of plots in a list in to a composite plot?

Tags: altair

I've normally generated and appended charts to a list in order to later combine them (e.g. sequential multi-year plots for a given location).

For instance:

```
group1= (chart1 + line1 + point1_hist + min_max_rule + point_max_hist + point_min_hist | legend1)  

plot_group.append(group1)
```

And then creating a final chart from this list.

```
chart= plot_group[0] & plot_group[1] & plot_group[2] & plot_group[3]
```

This works fine for a fixed number of component plots.

But, for a variable number of plots, I can't figure how to automatically generate the final chart since the altar chart structure using '&' is not a standard python syntax that I can construct with a simple loop, as far as I can tell.

Is there any convention in Altair to simply concatenate a series of plots in a list in to a composite plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` operator is a shortcut for `alt.vconcat`, which can accept multiple arguments:

```
chart=alt.vconcat(*plot_group)
```